# Generalized Dyck words with alphabet of size $k$

Tags: combinatorics

It is known (e.g., [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number#Applications_in_combinatorics)) that the Catalan number $C_n$ is the number of Dyck words of length $2n$, where a Dyck word is a string consisting of $n$ $X$'s and $n$ $Y$'s such that no initial segment of the string has more $Y$'s than $X$'s.

What if we generalize Dyck words to an alphabet of size $k$ for any $k\geq 2$? We have letters $X_1,\ldots,X_k$, and for any initial segment, the number of $X_k$'s is no greater than the number of $X_{k-1}$'s, which in turn is no greater than the number of $X_{k-2}$'s, and so on to $X_1$.

How many generalized Dyck words of length $kn$ are there, where each letter appears exactly $n$ times?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These sequences are listed in OEIS as the n-dimensional Catalan numbers:

- k=2: [A000108](http://oeis.org/A000108), formula $\frac{(2n)!}{n!(n+1)!}$
- k=3: [A005789](http://oeis.org/A005789), formula $\frac{2(3n)!}{n!(n+1)!(n+2)!}$
- k=4: [A005790](http://oeis.org/A005790), formula $\frac{12(4n)!}{n!(n+1)!(n+2)!(n+3)!}$
- k=5: [A005791](http://oeis.org/A005791), formula $\frac{288(5n)!}{n!(n+1)!(n+2)!(n+3)!(n+4)!}$

The general formula is $$(kn)!\prod_{i=0}^{k-1}\frac{i!}{(n+i)!}$$ If you want to find a proof, I would start by chasing down the references of [Multidimensional Catalan and related numbers as Hausdorff moments](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1304.6008v2.pdf), Katarzyna Górska and Karol A. Penson.

PS Pleasingly the general formula works even in the cases $k \in \{0, 1\}$.